# Load JQuery before Select2 in Typescript (Power BI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-select2, powerbi

I'm trying to use Select2 in a Power BI custom visual. I have downloaded the .js files and typings files for both JQuery and Select2 and added their paths in the projects.

pbiviz.json

```
{...
"externalJS": [
"node_modules/powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils/lib/index.js",
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js"
],...
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{...,
"files": [
".api/v1.7.0/PowerBI-visuals.d.ts",
"node_modules/powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils/lib/index.d.ts",
"node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts",
"node_modules/@types/select2/index.d.ts",
"src/settings.ts",
"src/visual.ts"
],...
}
```

There is a triple slash directive in the select2/index.d.ts file

```
/// <reference types = "jquery"/>
```

And I have also placed one at the beginning of my Power BI visual.ts file

```
/// <reference path = "C:/PBI/mySelect2/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts"/>
```

When I compile the code, I don't get any errors, but then once I try to create the visual in Power BI service, I get the following error in the console:

```
Select2: An instance of jQuery or a jQuery-compatible library was not found. Make sure that you are including jQuery before Select2 on your web page.
```

Not sure how to get this working or what is happening. If someone has an idea, I would love to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you packaging with `pbiviz package`?

Comment: No, I've only tried `pbiviz start` so far. I also neglected to mention the versions of the libraries:
"@types/jquery": "^2.0.47",
"@types/select2": "^4.0.41",
"jquery": "^2.2.4",
"select2": "^4.0.3"